# Split ruby string and then swap two elements in that array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails and react app and i noticed i have been logging the date into my backend as day/month/year instead of month/day/year. what is the best way to go into my rails backend and fix theses dates. For example I want to turn "7/3/2018" into "3/7/2018" (yes they are strings).

I'm assuming i would start off with something like this:

```
 date = "7/3/2018"
 date.split("/")
```

but then how will i swap the values? Or is there a better way to do this other than to use split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get each value in the array from the splitted string, and then interpolate them in a new string in the order you need:

```
date = '7/3/2018'
month, day, year = date.split('/')
p "#{day}/#{month}/#{year}" # "3/7/2018"
```

Other way could be using Date#parse and strftime to handle the format output:

```
require 'date'

date = '7/3/2018'
p Date.parse(date).strftime('%m/%d/%Y') # "03/07/2018"
```